# How to get USDT TRC20 transaction hash using API

Tags: python, hash, tron

I can't find a normal answer how to get the hash of a transaction, I want to use this to get notifications of new transactions, and at the same time get their hash

I tried to use the official API (https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/account), but making a request I did not get the hash

Comment: had you found solution to your question?

Comment: Yes, I use this link https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/contract/events?address={address} to get an answer with the values I want